# I dried my filament because it wouldn't adhere properly but now it adheres a bit too well

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, adhesion

I dried my spool of PLA this morning to solve adhesion issues and proceeded to print the model that failed due to the aforementioned issues. But when it was done and I went to remove it from the bed, it wouldn't budge; even the scraper that comes with the Ender 3 didn't help. I require immediate assistance.

Comment: I see that you solved your problem, but if you have PLA adhering so tight that it's hard to get off or looks like it's damaging your bed surface, you probably have your nozzle too close to the bed and/or your bed too hot. Check your leveling to avoid having the same thing happen again, leading to premature bed surface wear.

Answer (score 4):

I removed the mat from the bed and popped the print off